# How to disable button if there is no input entered including space char in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a simple input field and 1 button for save it. If the input field is empty, then button becomes disabled. But with my code, space character is acting like normal character so user can enter value by just putting space. How can i check at least 1 char exist on input field?

the code:

```
<mat-form-field fxFlex="50">
            <input matInput name="postalAddress"
                   [(ngModel)]="employee.postalAddress" placeholder="Postal Address"
                   required>
</mat-form-field>

 <button type="button" id="save" class="button-style" (click)="onSaveOffice()"
                [disabled]="!employee.postalAddress" > Save
 </button>
```

Note: I am using typescript at back so do i need to do any logic at typescript code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `trim()` method on string before checking emptiness, so it will remove all the spaces:

```
<mat-form-field fxFlex="50">
            <input matInput name="postalAddress"
                   [(ngModel)]="employee.postalAddress" placeholder="Postal Address"
                   required>
</mat-form-field>

 <button type="button" id="save" class="button-style" (click)="onSaveOffice()"
                [disabled]="!employee.postalAddress?.trim()" > Save
 </button>
```

Hope that helps.